# Spawning a thread from an Activity in Android need advice on re-factoring

Tags: android, multithreading, notifications

I have developed a file downloader which shows progress in the notification bar (Like Android Market Downloads). I have based my work [on this example](https://github.com/nheid/unitedcoders-android/blob/master/src/com/unitedcoders/android/examples/download/DownloadProgress.java).

In My activity i start a download thread like

```
private void startDownload() {
         DownLoadFileHandler filedownLoad = new DownLoadFileHandler(this, getIntent().getDataString(),mDirectory,mFileName.getText().toString(),mHandler);
         filedownLoad.downloadfile();
             finish();  //End the Spawning activity
    }
```

Run function in the download thread

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
       //do some pre processing 
       setupNotification();
       //while downloading keep updating notification with flag FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT
       Once Download is complete change the flag FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL and update for the final
       time
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
    if(notificationManager != null)               
              notificationManager.cancel(DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION);
     }
}
```

Now I noticed that while downloading files if i make/receive a call for a substantial amount of time (on a 2g network which does not support calling and net at the same time), the thread dies, disappears  and  my notification for the incomplete downloads remain stuck as an on going notification in the notification bar  which can only be cleared on rebooting.

I feel that i have down spawning a thread from an Activity(the only activity at that time in the application) and then calling finish on it is a mistake on my part. So i need to re factor the code.

My questions what exactly am I doing wrong in this approach (as download seems to  work with notification updates if there is no call)

What should be the best approach to address the issue as outlined above ?

Answer (score 0):

For a long running action like a file download that you want to keep running even if your Activity is not in the foreground, you should consider using a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) instead.

Comment: so should I spawn new threads from service? This will work with parallel downloads right? Also is there any way to control the about "thread deaths" which leaves my ongoing notification hanging. (Apparently it does not seems to reach the catch block)

Comment: Also in my case i will call finish on the activity as soon as i start the service.What problems can this cause?